# Problems with a login php script - passing objects through a session

Tags: php, session, object, login-script

I have an index.php page that creates a new Login class (login class does all the handling of data,creating session, redirecting, etc)

index.php I create a new login class

```
  require_once('login.class.php');  
  $login = new Login;
```

Login constructor looks like this

```
public function __construct(){
    // Start session and open a database connection 
    session_start();
    $this->connectToDB();
}
```

if the user logs in successfully, I redirect him to securePage.php.

if I do the following on the securePage.php

```
$test = $_SESSION ['usrData'];
var_export($test->getFirstName());
var_export($test->getLastName());
var_export($test->isAuthorized());
```

it displays the following error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getFirstName() on a non-object
>   in /login/securePage.php on line
>   17

When, however, I put

```
$login = new Login;
```

in front of

```
var_export($test->getFirstName());
var_export($test->getLastName());
var_export($test->isAuthorized());
```

It works! I dont' know what gives and if I am doing something wrong because even when I put

```
session_start();
```

instead of

```
$login = new Login;
```

but it still gives me the error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getFirstName() on a non-object
>   in /login/securePage.php on line
>   16

Comment: What is the result of `var_export($login);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with the variable name. If I am not wrong, in your securePage.php, here is the code:

```
$login = $_SESSION ['usrData'];
var_export($login);
var_export($test->getFirstName());
```

It should be:

```
$login = $_SESSION ['usrData'];
var_export($login);
var_export($login->getFirstName());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Crap! You are right! With all the testing I was doing, I've totally messed up the variable names in var_exports. Besides that session_start() in the constructor. How does the rest of the code look like in terms of the OOP design?

Comment: I am not an expert in OOP though. But, from what I can see and understand about OOP, I think your design looks fine for me. But, maybe some expert in OOP can help you more about that. =)

Answer (score 1):

Could be a couple of things:

-You have to do a session_start() at the top of any page that uses sessions.

-With a serialized object (an object stored in a session variable), the object class needs to have been included anywhere it is being referenced.

Looks more likely to be that you didn't session_start()?

Also resource variables (database handles, file handles, etc) won't survive the serialization/deserialization that happens with session variables.

Comment: I do have session_start at the top of the page but it still gives the same error..

Comment: You should not be doing a session_start() in the constructor of your object.  That is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Can I have a separate function in my class that will do session_start() ?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by
"With a serialized object (an object stored in a session variable), the object class needs to have been included anywhere it is being referenced."

Comment: I mean that if you have a script that attempts to utilize a serialized object (in this case an object that was stored in a session variable) in a script where the class definition for the object has not been included you'll get an error.  Also to answer your other question, yes you could session_start in a different method.  However session_start is basically a php utility -- it sets up the session environment and automatically unserializes variables and makes them available in the $_SESSION superglob.

Comment: It's something that should just be done in all your scripts, and shouldn't be tied to a login object.  IF anything -- have a separate session class and initialize that. My best guess on your problem was that you were doing session_start twice, which would clobber the $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good practice to close the session before issuing the redirect (although I'd expect its unlikely that the session is not being written until after the browser requests the new page).

What does the line 'var_export($login);' within securePage.php generate? (comment out the calls which are causing the fatal error).